# Unable to order a list using both OrderBy or Sort

Tags: c#, sorting

So I am trying to sort a file out in a descending order.
The text file looks something like this:

%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006376][EVENT=agentStateEvent][queue=79651][agentID=61871][extension=22801][state=2][reason=0]%

%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102][EVENT=agentStateEvent][queue=79654][agentID=62278][extension=22828][state=2][reason=0]%

%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006105][EVENT=CallControlTerminalConnectionTalking][callID=2619][ucid=10000026191441907765][deviceType=1][deviceName=21775][Queue=][Trunk=384:82][TrunkType=1][TrunkState=1][Cause=100][CalledDeviceID=07956679058][CallingDeviceID=21775][extension=21775]%

and basically I want the end result to only output unique values of the timestamp. I have used substring to get rid of the excess text, and it outputs fine as shown below:

[TIMESTAMP=1441737006376]

[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]

[TIMESTAMP=1441737006105]

however i want it to order in the following order (basically numeric descending to ascending):

[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]

[TIMESTAMP=1441737006105]

[TIMESTAMP=1441737006376]

I have tried the .sort and .orderBy but not having any joy. I wouldve using this prior to doing any substring formatting wouldve sufficed but clearly not.

Code is as follows:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FedSorter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            string readIn = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1.txt";
            System.IO.TextWriter writeOut = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1_new.txt");
            List<String> list = new List<String>();

            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(readIn);
            string contents = "";
            string checkValues = "";
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string text = line;
                text = text.Substring(1, 25);
                if (!checkValues.Contains(text))
                {
                    list.Add(text);
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                    writeOut.WriteLine(text);
                    counter++;
                }

                contents = text;
                checkValues += contents + ",";
            }
            list = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            writeOut.Close();
            file.Close();
            orderingFile();

        }
        public static void orderingFile()
        {
            string line = "";
            string readIn = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1_new.txt";
            System.IO.TextWriter writeOut = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1_new2.txt");
            List<String> ordering = new List<String>();
            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(readIn);
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                ordering.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
                ordering.Add(line);
                writeOut.WriteLine(line);
            }
            writeOut.Close();
            file.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from @juharr's correct answer, you would do well to take advantage of LINQ to simplify your code greatly.

```
string readIn = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1.txt";
var timestamps = File.ReadAllLines(readIn)
                     .Select(l => l.Substring(1, 25))
                     .Distinct()
                     .OrderBy(t => t)
                     .ToArray();
```

To write out the values, you can either use a `foreach` on `timestamps` and write out each line to your `TextWriter`, or you can use the `File` class again:

```
string readOut = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1_new.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(readOut, timestamps); 
//notice I've changed it to ToArray in the first part instead of ToList.
```

Comment: Why would you post this if you even admit it is not an answer?

Comment: @DangerZone Because it's too long to be a comment and I feel OP and future readers could benefit from it.

Comment: Actually this is looking more like an answer as I think the OP wants the sorted results in the output file since they're not using the lists that they are sorting anyway.

Comment: This is alot more what I want. However only issue is how do I write out the unique values because writeout.writeline(timestamps) outputs  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]. PS why has my question been given a negative :/

Comment: @MubeenHussain I've expanded on it to show how to write the values out. To be honest I'm not sure why your question was downvoted. It is clear what you are trying to achieve, there is an example input and desired output, and there is complete code. Perhaps someone found the issue too trivial.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new list and you need to assign it to the variable

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

However it doesn't look like you even use `list` after you create and sort it.  Additionally you have the same issue in the `orderingFile` method with

```
ordering.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

However instead of sorting and creating a new list on each line it would be better to use a [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx) that will keep the contents sorted as you add to it.

But again you are not actually using the `ordering` list after you finish adding to it in the `foreach`.  If you are looking to read the values in a file, sort them and then output them to another file, then you need to do it in that order.

Comment: Am  I calling this in the right place because im still getting the same issue :(

Comment: Ive added a second method just to reread the new file back in and try reordering but no joy

Comment: That will only effect the ordering in the list referenced by the `list` variable.   Are you trying to reorder the values written to the "ex1_new.txt" file?  Note you have the same problem with `ordering.OrderBy(x => x).ToList()`.